# Typescript error TS2583 Cannot find name 'Set'

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript

I have just started learning Typescript today and when I run tsc app.ts I get 11 errors but I thought I would start with the first. Tried updating tsconfig.json problems seem to be with node_modules.Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

error states - ../../../node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:411:23 - error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library? Try changing the 'lib' compiler option to 'es2015' or later.

```
"compilerOptions": {
     "target": "es6",                                
     "module": "commonjs",                           
     "lib": ["es6"], 
     "noImplicitAny": true,
     "declaration": true,
     "outDir": "./lib",
     "strict": false,
     "esModuleInterop": true,
     "skipLibCheck": true,
     "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true
},
"include": ["./src"],
"exclude": ["node_modules"]
```

Comment: Did you try what the error message suggests, changing 'lib' option to 'es2015'? Also, what's the context of your issue? Are you trying to run a React app with typescript or what else?

Comment: I am only running a basic 
index.html
app.ts
package.json (with lock)
tsconfig.json
.gitignore
node_modules folder (none of the errors are for files in this folder)

Also: I tried es2015 no difference.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio add the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package.

I also had this problem in a number of my SPAs in a .NET 5 core project. It seems like every time I added a Typescript file manually I would get these errors. I tried all of the different suggestions here on this site but nothing worked. So I paid attention the next time I added a typescript file maually. A pop up mentioned adding the Microsoft.TypeScript.MSBuild package. I did and all the errors went away.

Now, I don't use VSCode, so I don't know if it works the same or not but this worked in Visual Studio 2019.

Comment: Thanks. I'll try your suggestion. This is driving me nuts.

Answer (score 0):

try `npm install @types/node`. Worked for me in VSCode.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

I also used `npm install @types/node` and it worked.

By default, TypeScript doesn't have the type declarations for different libraries (for example lodash, or, in this case, Node.js) unless you explicitly install them.

So, the above command provides those type definitions for types specific to Node.js, including Set.

You can read more about it in the [TypeScript documentation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/consumption.html#definitelytyped-and-types).