# TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set'. Do you need to change your target library?

Tags: javascript, typescript, intellij-idea, webstorm

I'm getting error TS2583: Cannot find name 'Set' in my IDE. This is my tsconfig:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "es2015"
    ]
}
```

I have "Use tsconfig.json" selected in Languages & Frameworks > Typescript settings.

If I add this directive to the top of the file the error goes away.

```
/// <reference lib="es2015"/>
```

My project's generated JavaScript needs to run in Internet Explorer 11.
Will adding this directive cause TypeScript's compiler to generate JavaScript that is not compatible with Internet Explorer 11?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript error TS2583 Cannot find name 'Set'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68659611/typescript-error-ts2583-cannot-find-name-set)